# select checkboxes and show up row - React js

Tags: reactjs

How to write dynamic checkboxes using react redux. Actually, I want to show up in the last Row when we click all checkboxes it shows up in the last row hyperlink.

When we select all checkboxes and show up the last link row part of the below code. If we uncheck the last row will hide.

Here I am using react-bootstrap.
Please help with this

```
 <div>
    <Row>
      <Col>
        <h1 >
          test
        </h1>
      </Col>
    </Row>
    {orders.map((order, index) => (
    <Row className="mt-4" key={index}>
      <Col>
        <Form.Check
          type="checkbox"
          label={order.name}
            name={order.name}
            onChange ={handleChange}
        />
      </Col>
      </Row>
    ))}

    <Row className="mt-4">
    {isAllChecked && (

      <Col>
        <h2l>
          <strong>test?</strong>
        </h2>
        </Col>
    )}
    </Row>
    <Row>
    {isAllChecked && (
      <Col>
        <Link to="/test3" style={{ color: '#009540', fontSize: '20px' }}>
          click here
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faArrowRight}
            style={{ color: '#009540', marginBottom: '-3px' }}
          />{' '}
        </Link>
        </Col>
    )}
      </Row>

  </div>
```

Comment: Where does this code render any checkboxes? Where does it use redux? Can you clarify what you want or what the issue is?

Comment: If I select all checkboxes I want to display last (Fortsatt uten nett?) div otherwise hide it

Comment: Oh, I see now. And what have you tried already to accomplish this?

Comment: Please check updated code

Comment: I saw that, but I don't see where you try to check if all checkboxes are selected or conditionally hide the div.

Comment: I stuck there.  I don't know how to do that in react.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235576/discussion-between-venusri-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the `orders` array and check that every element has a truthy `isChecked` property.

[Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

> The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the
> test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

```
const isAllChecked = orders.every(({ isChecked }) => isChecked);
```

Then conditionally render the "Fortsatt uten nett?" div.

[Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

```
{
  isAllChecked && (
    <HomenetText headingSmall>
      <strong>Fortsatt uten nett?</strong>
    </HomenetText>
  )
}
```